# How to copy SQLite db from data/data folder on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I want to copy my local `SQLite` database out of `data/data` folder and see its content in some db browser for debug purposes.

Is there any way how to copy it out to root folder?

I used this function 2 months ago, but as I updated my Android Studio from 3.5 to 4.1, it is not working anymore. I cant even see content of `databases` folder using `adb shell`. It says `Permission denied` on both debug and release build version.

```
fun backupDatabase(){
        try {
            val sd: File = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                val currentDBPath = "/data/data/${app.packageName}/databases/$DB_NAME"
                val backupDBPath = "backupDB.db"
                val currentDB = File(currentDBPath)
                val backupDB = File(sd, backupDBPath)
                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    val src: FileChannel = FileInputStream(currentDB).channel
                    val dst: FileChannel = FileOutputStream(backupDB).channel
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size())
                    src.close()
                    dst.close()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            App.log("BackupEx: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }
```

Comment: You use .exists() which is ok but you dont display a toast if not. So the user knows nothing and we neither as you did not tell. Please inform us better.

Comment: As it is unclear for which path exactly you get a permission denied. Inform us better.

Comment: You did not tell us if you have any exception.

Comment: No exception was thrown. I did `cd: /data/data/packageName/databases/` and used `ls` there and got Permission Denied

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this directory pattern in your Device Explorer on Android Studio.**

*data -> data -> com.example.appname -> databases.*

Then you copy three files:
One with your database name, the other with a "-shm" suffix and another with a "-wal" suffix.

Open all of these files in your SQLite browser.